# Notepad++ starting REALLY slow and not showing text

Tags: ide, notepad++

I'm just going crazy about this but I can't find a solution so I'm here to ask for a help.

I've always used Notepad++ but since I've updated to Windows 10 it started not working.

When I open it N++ takes a long time (like.... A LONG time) to be operative (in the meanwhile it stays in "Not Responding").

When finally it unfreezes and I open a file, no text is shown BUT if I try to copy something and paste it somewhere else it does it correctly so I guess it's not a problem of encoding of stuff like these.....

I've tried many times to uninstall N++, clear all the files on the HDD and even eliminate registry keys but when I install it again nothing changes....

I'm desperate please help me!!!

Answer (score 6):

Some ideas to try to identify the problem:

1. Make sure you don't have any file loaded before closing notepad++. Specially files on net shares
2. If using the project tree Window (Folder as Workspace), try to close it. Specially if you have a huge workspace
3. Check executable compatibility mode. Is it changed?
4. Disable any 'check for updates' option (this includes notepad++ check for itself and also all plugins that have a similar option)
5. Uninstall/disable any notepad++ plugin
6. Try with a portable version. On the notepad++ site there are both installers and zip packages
7. Try with 32bit and 64bit versions
8. Try to delete this folder: "%APPDATA%\Notepad++" (maps to C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++)
9. Try to temporarily disable the antivirus. Or add some exception to the path of Notepad++/Notepad++ portable
10. Create a clean new user and run it from there. Perhaps this is something wrong with some registry keys, so a clean state could work

The official site is [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/). (Just in case you downloaded it from elsewhere)

Comment: tried everything you wrote with no success at all :(

I'm starting to believe the only solution is to format the HDD...

Comment: Try disabling the antivirus temporarily. Or add some exception to the path of Notepad++ portable.

Comment: Also, try to delete this folder: "%APPDATA%\Notepad++\"   (maps to D:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++)

Comment: When you open notepad++ ant it is 'frozen', what do you seen on "task manager"? Does the process of notepad++ use some cpu or does some disk/network activity?

Comment: already deleted that folder and disabled the antivirus. When n++ freezes the task manager says "Not Responding" but still shows that it uses around 20% of the CPU. Aside from this if I right click on the process and then select "Go to service(s)" it criptically brings me to NetTcpPortSharing...........

Comment: Just another idea: Create a new clean new user and run it from there. Perhaps this is something wrong with some registry keys, so a clean state could work.

Comment: The question is closed for answer so I post a comment here instead; I had a similar issue. I just figured out that for my case (not necessarily for everyone) it was because I had this project tree opened (File -> Open Folders as Workspace) on the left side of the editor. If the the directory structure for the project is huge, it will take some time for Notepad++ to go through the file system to build a tree. When closing the tree view, it goes well.

If you have a huge workspace, closing the project tree (Folder as Workspace) window may help..

Comment: found the problem for me : plugins - xml - check for updates at startup : unchecked it and I went from 30s to 0s for startup time

Answer (score 5):

I started having this issue too recently, and found that I had opened up a text file on my network at work, made some changes but hadn't saved it.  Then when I got home (where I didn't have access to the network) Notepad++ opened really slow...

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution earlier and it seems like I fixed it myself by updating the application manually (even though "auto-updater" was on). Now the startup times are greatly improved.

Go to Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager. Click the "Updates" tab. Hit the Update button and restart the application until your list of obsolete components / plugins is empty.